# Vector of a Fixed size array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have had a look around for different sources and was unable to find any useful information on vectors of fixed size arrays. I was wondering if the below code would work properly.

```
std::vector<std::array<myType, [3]> > myVectorOfArrays;
```

Comment: maybe an aside, but using a `struct` will definitely work and probably make your code more readable / usable.

Comment: if you remove the [] it will

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try: `std::vector<std::array<myType, 3> > myVectorOfArrays;`