# How to add a value to a vector of arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I need to create a vector where each value is in fact four values.  So good old Google led me to these pages:

[Vector of a Fixed size array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915556/vector-of-a-fixed-size-array)

[Cant make a vector of fixed size arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970624/cant-make-a-vector-of-fixed-size-arrays)

[Vector of vectors, reserve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991765/vector-of-vectors-reserve)

From these threads I'm led to believe it is optimal with the following syntax:

```
std::vector<std::array<unsigned int, 4>> arrayVector;
```

That part seems to work, but now I'd like to add my first row of values:

```
arrayVector.push_back({ 0, 1, 2, 3 });
```

And that part does not compile:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error (active)      no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=std::array, _Alloc=std::allocator>]" matches the argument list

I've also tried creating the int array as a separate variable and passing that variable to the push_back, also with the same result.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015, I'm not one to normally choose C++, so I might be missing something obvious.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to compile for me [on IdeOne](https://ideone.com/kogZIJ)...

Comment: Your code gave me a big clue that nobody mentioned in those other threads: #include <array> :D  That could be it.  I didn't think to check that because there was no compilation error for the first line where the std::array is used.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
arrayVector.push_back({{ 0, 1, 2, 3 }});
```

Older versions of Clang (for example) require the extra braces, for example--the reason seems to be that you're initializing the C-style array inside the `std::array`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to do the trick for me.  It might help others though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    arrayVector.push_back(std::array<unsigned int, 4>{0, 1, 2, 3});
```

Comment: That gives two errors: "incomplete type is not allowed" and "too many initializer values"

Comment: it compiles for me using g++ 5.4. p.s. i just saw your comment about the header file. i think everyone assumed that it had been included (behind the scenes so to speak). cheers.